# Using Either recursively

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, either

So I have defined a function like this one below:

```
myFunction :: String -> Either String MyType
```

I am reading String until the end. `Left` is used for handling errors. `Right` suppose to return me the tuple. In `myFunction` I am calling `anotherFunction` and checking if it returns `Left` or `Right` like this:

```
myFunction :: String -> Either String MyType
myFunction "" = Right -- want to return MyType here
myFunction s = 
     case anotherFunction s of
         Left c -> Left c
         Right (v1, v2, t) -> -- want to call myFunction again with t
```

When `anotherFunction` returns `Right`, I want to call `myFunction` again recursively without loosing `v1` and `v2`. How can I achieve that with recursion?

Here is the exact definition of MyType:

```
data MyType = MyString String | MyInt Int | MyMap [(String, MyType)] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but I think what you want is just the `>>=` operator. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I think it would help if you add a simple example. For example some mapping from a `Char` to some 2-tuple of `Int`s to illustrate what you aim to do.

Comment: What is `MyType`?

Comment: MyType has a JLMap [(String, MyType)] which is, I believe, needed here

Comment: @Aivaras Could you give the exact definition of `MyType`?

Comment: @David yes, edited my question

Comment: What I want to achieve here is to add v1 and v2 to a tuple and add that tuple to a list, where list could have more than one tuple. And at the end return my desired list

Comment: Looks like `MyType` is some sort of generic "value" type.  It will need to be able to represent lists of tuples, which it currently does not, if you want to add a tuple to a list and call it a `MyType`.